# System.DllNotFoundException Crypt32.dll assembly:<unknown assembly> type:<unknown type> member:(null) on Xamarin Android in AWS Constructor

Tags: amazon-web-services, xamarin, xamarin.android

I get an exception when creating an instance of my subclass of CognitoAWSCredentials on Xamarin.Android.

```
**System.DllNotFoundException:** 'Crypt32.dll assembly:<unknown assembly> type:<unknown type> member:(null)'
```

Answer (score 0):

Just ignore the exception, and the next 3 - The library will catch it and handle them.

```
**System.InvalidOperationException:** 'The app.config/web.config files for the application did not contain region information'

**System.InvalidOperationException:** 'The environment variable AWS_REGION was not set with AWS region data.'

**System.InvalidOperationException:** 'Unable to find a profile named 'default' in store Amazon.Runtime.CredentialManagement.CredentialProfileStoreChain'
```

Credits

- [@Ryan Niebur](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6802494)
- https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-net/issues/1431